# How to connect to remote python with jedi.el?

Tags: python, jedi

How can I connect to remote python with `jedi.el`? I need to use remote virtualenv for getting possible completions, docs, etc.

Comment: I have a stalled WIP branch that tries to add this functionality: https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi/pull/304